# Is this code thread safe in a Spring application?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

The ResourceMapping "filter" is accessed from .jsp page using Ajax request.

My understanding is that Spring will create a new thread of execution each time
the resource "filter" is accessed. Since FilterItems is a Spring @Component bean
and is therfore a singleton then multiple threads (crated by calls to resource "filter)will access this same instance.
A new instance of FilterItems is instantiated with each each call to "filter"
resource, as each instance is not shared between threads then this is thread safe ?

Is invocation of FilterItems.filter1 & FilterItems.filter2
threadSafe ?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MyController {
@ResourceMapping(value = "filter") 
    public void filter(){

        FilterItems t = new FilterItems();
        LinkedList<MyObj> l = new LinkedList<MyObj>();
        l.add(new MyObj("1"));
        l.add(new MyObj("2"));

        System.out.println("size is : " + l.size());

        t.filterItem1(l);       
        System.out.println("size is : " + l.size());

        t.filterItem2(l);   
        System.out.println("size is : " + l.size());
    }
}

*****************************************************************************

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

@Component
public class FilterItems {

    public void filterItem1(LinkedList<MyObj> l) {

        Iterator<MyObj> iter = l.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            MyObj myObj = iter.next();

            if (myObj.param.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public void filterItem2(LinkedList<MyObj> l) {

        Iterator<MyObj> iter = l.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            MyObj myObj = iter.next();

            if (myObj.param.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class MyObj {

        public final String param;

        public MyObj(String param) {
            this.param = param;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller code has no dependencies on shared mutable data, it only handles data local to a single method invocation. That means that the code is thread-safe.

It isn't clear, though, how `MyController` manages to invoke private methods on `FilterItems`, or how it instantiates a foreign private static class `MyObj`.

Comment: thanks, ive changed visibility to public instead of private for method calls

Answer (score 0):

It is <s>almost</s> thread-safe as <s>almost</s> all your data is stored in local variables and passed as parameters.

The only possible exception is the `param` field of `MyObj`, which should be `final` to guarantee that the same value is seen by everyone after object creation.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its
>   constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an
>   object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed
>   to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final
>   fields.

But so long as `MyObj` class is kept `private` and no-one else can possibly instantiate them, that won't be a problem.

Comment: For that matter, the `LinkedList` he uses is also mutable, but that doesn't cause troubles in his particular code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, it's only created as a local variable and passed as parameter so it won't be visible by any other threads.

Comment: How is that different from `MyObj` instances? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, you're right, I missed the fact `MyObj` class is declared as  `private`. I thought they could in theory be instantiated by someone else too. I updated my answer.

Comment: Again, `LinkedList` is a public, mutable, thread-unsafe class, but that doesn't make its usage in OP's particular code problematic. The answer which raises an issue with `MyObj` must also raise issues with both `FilterItems` methods because they mutate a thread-unsafe object and may cause thread-safety issues when used differently from what was posted. My opinion is that such considerations should not be entertained in this context.